# where the links to previous versions of file are located in git

Tags: git

In Git book there is a phrase

"To be efficient, if files have not changed, Git doesn’t store the file again—just a link to the previous identical file it has already stored"

So all the git object are stored in the folder `.git\objects`. And when I commit - it adds folder for new commit and the folders for all new files(folder name - first two symbols of hash code as far as I can see).

But the question is - how git operates with not changed files? where are the references/link kept in git repository? I mean how does `commit` knows that it should reference to a certain not changed file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question we have to consider three types of Git objects: blob, tree, and commit.

A *blob* is basically a compressed version of a file with a hash. Blobs with the same hash have identical content.

A *tree* binds together multiple blobs or other trees, acting like a directory in a normal file system. A tree again has a hash, similar to a blob. But instead of calculating the hash from the files' contents, a tree hash is calculated from the files reference from the tree. Simply speaking a tree looks like the following, linking file names to blobs:

```
file1      deadbeef
file2      decafbad
file3      42c0ffee
file4      deadbeef
```

As we can immediately see from the tree listing, `file1` and `file4` reference the same blob and therefor share the same content (which is only stored once on disk).

Now, the above did not assume anything about history or changes of files and directories. Blobs and trees are very simple data structures to represent a particular snapshot of a repository. To store temporal relationship between trees, Git introduces the concept of *commit* objects. A commit object contains the author's and committer's name + email, a timestamp, a commit message, and more importantly a reference to a tree object, and lastly a reference to one or more parent commit objects. Simply put:

```
Author: John Doe <j.doe@example.com>
Committer: John Doe<j.doe@example.com>
Timestamp: 1234567890
Tree: cafebabe
Parent: 123f00ba
Message: this is a commit with a single parent.
```

As you can see from the above, anything that has not changed between commits can still be referenced by the same hash (hashes are constant, same hash = same object)

Comment: so those trees are some files stored in `objects` folder?

Comment: @user1432980: yes, every Git object type (blob, tree, commit, annotated tag) is stored in the `objects` folder, given that you have not repacked your repository. Otherwise they will be found in the `*.pack` files.